# Assigning the result of bundle.getString() to a String throws a ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-bundle

I have an instance of a `Place Object` called `spiliaBeach` which takes in the arguments you see below:

```
public PlaceObject spiliaBeach = new PlaceObject(R.string.spilia_beach,R.string.spilia_description,"2 Km from the Port",R.string.beach_category);
```

PlaceObject.java class:

```
private int name = 0;
private int description = 0;
private String locationDistance = "distance";
private int category = 0;

PlaceObject(int name, int description, String locationDistance, int category) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.locationDistance = locationDistance;
    this.category = category;
}
```

In the `MainActivity` i pass that data through a `Bundle` to my `DetailsActivity` like so :

```
Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
Bundle intentBundle = new Bundle();
intentBundle.putInt("name",beachDB.spiliaBeach.getName());
intentBundle.putInt("description",beachDB.spiliaBeach.getDescription());
intentBundle.putString("distance",beachDB.spiliaBeach.getLocationDistance());
//Log.d(TAG,"Location distance : " + beachDB.spiliaBeach.getLocationDistance());
//intentBundle.putInt("category",beachDB.spiliaBeach.getCategory());
detailsIntent.putExtra("data",intentBundle);
startActivity(detailsIntent);
```

and try to retrieve it like this inside the `onCreate()` of `DetailsActivity` :

```
private void getIntentData(Intent intent) {
    Bundle dataBundle = intent.getBundleExtra("data");
    if(dataBundle != null) {
        name = dataBundle.getInt(NAME_KEY);
        description = dataBundle.getInt(DESC_KEY);
        locationDistance = dataBundle.getString(LOC_DIST_KEY);
        Log.d(TAG, "location distance : " + locationDistance + '\n' + "description : " + description);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG,"Bundle is null");
    }
}
```

but the logcat says that the `locationDistance` variable is `null` and it throws a `ClassCastException` saying that the String returned cannot be cast to an Integer when nothing is an Integer directly in that line, right? Any ideas why?

Comment: you are using *magic variables*, which may differ from constants. Use same **constant** for putting and retrieving values

Comment: alsso show full exception stacktrace and the line on which it happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your `PlaceObject` class as Parcelable and implement all required methods as per guide https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidParcelable/article.html

Then you will be able to save the object as

```
intentBundle.putParcelable(placeObject);
```

and retrieve it as

```
Bundle dataBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
PlaceObject object = (PlaceObject) dataBundle.getParcelable(KEY);
```

**EDIT:** you pass `R.string.spilia_beach` which is integer id, in order to get a string use getString(R.string.spilia_beach) etc

Comment: Thank you for the info. `Parcelable` objects seem like a life saver now